# Vagrant 'permission denied' on Windows

Tags: windows, centos, vagrant

I am having trouble accessing files through Vagrant on Windows. I have been using it on OS X for quite some time and have my Vagrantfile setup correctly which works every time.

I have sent my colleague the same Vagrant file, he is on Windows and receives 'Permission Denied' when trying to access files through the browser.

Just to be clear, the permission errors are returned by the server when accessing 'dev.local' in the browser and not from Vagrant itself... it will be a configuration error on Windows or within the VM.

The VM is CentOS 6.5

```
Vagrantfile:
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "chef/centos-6.5"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.21"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "install.sh"
  config.vm.hostname = "dev.local"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/home", id: "vagrant", :nfs => false, :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=777"]
  config.ssh.insert_key = false
  config.ssh.username = "vagrant"
  config.ssh.password = "vagrant"
end
```

Can any Windows Vagrant users shed any light on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was VBGuestAdditions out of date. The permission error was caused by not being able to sync to my local folder (which contained an index.php) so it was using the servers /home folder which didn't contain anything and since viewing directory structure is disabled it returned permission errors.

I had 4.X.X installed, and VirtualBox is on 5.X.X Here is the fix:

run command: `vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest`

the run `vagrant up` which may still throw an error as the plugin fails to copy a file.

`vagrant ssh` to get into the box and run the following command:

`sudo ln -s /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-5.X.X/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions /usr/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions`

Replace 5.X.X with the version of your VirtualBox.

logout and run `vagrant reload`

do a happy dance